# Why is there an octave leap in this example from Gradus ad parnassum?

Tags: theory, counterpoint

[image]

In bars 5-6 the lower note  jumps an octave. Why is this good?

To me it sounds like it is not musical enough. Too big of a leap.  Please help me understand this octave leap.

I have seen octave leaps in hymn eg both tenor and bass being on sol with the bass jumping down to sol an octave lower but that sounded very good.

Comment: Couple of popular songs doing this - Somewhere Over the Rainbow and Heigh Ho. Don't know of any that 'break the rule' and continue further in the same direction.

Comment: Isn't an octave leap hard to sing?

Comment: Not any more than any other. Probably easier than, say, M7. If it was, why would songs have it?

Answer (score 5):

In this style, an octave leap (almost always ascending) is acceptable *as long as you resolve the leap in the opposite motion by step*. In other words, an ascending octave must then move immediately down by step.

In fact, this is true of most large leaps in this style. If you look at both voices of this example, you'll notice that *almost every* leap of a third or larger resolves with a step in the opposite direction. The only exception is the descending third in m. 4 of the lower voice; thirds don't always resolve by opposing step, but they often do.

Answer (score 0):

An example of the principle that Richard describes:

Comment: I thought that octave leaps were not really very vocal. Does this mean that I am trying to analyse counterpoint with vocal lines in my mind when it is not all about a composing for singers?

Comment: @Hank I can't answer that, except to say that counterpoint certainly isn't all about composing for singers, and to ask you why you don't seem to like "Somewhere over the Rainbow." :)